# How to force Grails GORM from retrieving back the info from the DB (.refresh() not working)

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have an issue where in Grails I set a flag on a database record -- another process sees the flag and updates the record status I then loop in grails through this record to get the changed status.

The problem is that grails NEVER retrieves again the record from the database and always gives me back the record i first fetched. I tried `.refresh()` `.withNewTransaction()` and `.withNewSession` all with no success.

So my main question how can I force gorm to refetch my instance from the database

Below is my code that is not working  :

```
    MyDomain.withNewTransaction {
        MyDomain myDomainInstance = MyDomain.get(params.id);

        myDomainInstance.opstatus = 9 /*REQUEST CANCEL OPERATION*/

        myDomainInstance.save();
        if (myDomainInstance.hasErrors()) {
            log.info "Cancel transaction error !: ";
            flash.message = message(code: 'error.occured');
            render view: "index"
            return
        }
    }

 MyDomain myDomainInstance = MyDomain.get(params.id);
        while (myDomainInstance.status == Status.SUCCESS.value /*the value should have changed to failed from the other process*/) {
            sleep(500);
            myDomainInstance.refresh();
        }
```

I added to the log

And I'm getting on refresh

```
2018-07-11 16:25:51,850 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] TRACE internal.DefaultRefreshEventListener  - Refreshing 
2018-07-11 16:25:52,180 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] TRACE internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  - Loading entity: [MyDomain#1113507]
2018-07-11 16:25:52,180 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] TRACE internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  - Attempting to resolve: [MyDomain#1113507]
2018-07-11 16:25:52,180 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] TRACE internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  - Resolved object in session cache: [MyDomain#1113507]
```

I'm guessing i need to clear my session cache in a way? how can i do this

Comment: Have you tried `save(flush: true)`?

Comment: Like @doelleri already mentioned - the issue may be not with retrieving fresh data, but with updating data in the db. Check if it has been already updated in db before reading it.

Comment: yes i tried save(flush: true) still same issue...actually i can see from the DB that the data has been updated

Comment: you could try to narrow this down by adding debug in your application for hibernate `trace 'org.hibernate.event.internal'`

Comment: Thanks @TuomasValtonen, I updated my question, it seems I need to clear my session cache somehow

Comment: actually it looks like it really gets loaded from the databas since you get that log-line after every `sleep`? Maybe the problem is the merge then? Anyway if you want to clear the session you can use: ```Session sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
sess.clear();``` and declare sessionFactory as a service injection

Comment: I tried what you said and `Object not resolved in any cache: [MyDomain#1113507]`. strangely the value is still the old one, even though it is changing from the database

Comment: As usual.. controller should be used only for receiving parameters and rendering output. All business logic should be(strongly recommend) in the service, please move logic into service and try again.